# i want to use assetmanager for an image

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-assetmanager

MyGdxGame.java

```
 public void print(){
    manager=new AssetManager();
    manager.load("selectlevel.png",Texture.class);
    manager.finishLoading();
    }
```

select level screen

```
 public void image(){
    Image img1=game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png"));
    }
```

what i get(

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture cannot be cast to
>   com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image

i dont want to change image type to Texture.

Comment: You are trying to set a Texture to the variable img1(which is an Image) . Try using Image img1= new Image(game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png")));

Comment: does not work aswell

Comment: @dfour cannot resolve constructor &#39;Image(java.lang.Object)&#39;

Comment: You will have to cast the Object to a texture like this 
Image img1= new Image((Texture)game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png"))); 
or call the get method with the class parameter like this 
Image img1= new Image(game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png",Texture.class)));

Comment: @dfour thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image

You are trying to place a Texture in a variable that is made for an scene2d.ui.Image. This will not work because a Texture and a scene2d.ui.Image are very different.

The scene2d.ui.Image has a constructor that takes a Texture so should be called like this:

```
Image imgVariable = new Image(i_am_a_Texture);
```

In the comments you mentioned you recieved an error

> cannot resolve constructor 'Image(java.lang.Object)'

This is saying that when you used the new Image constructor you passed it an Object and not a Texture which it was expecting.

In order to make the Object a Texture you could cast it to a Texture by adding (Texture) in from of the object you want cast like this:

```
 Texture textureVariable = (Texture) game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png"));
```

However the assetManager already has a way of saying what class the object returned should be and that is to add the class as the 2nd parameter like below

```
Texture textureVariable = game.manager().get(("selectlevel.png",Texture.class))
```